# Storing matrix after every iteration

Tags: r, loops, save, storing-data

I have following code.

```
for(i in 1:100)
{
   for(j in 1:100)
    R[i,j]=gcm(i,j)
}
```

`gcm()` is some function which returns a number based on the values of `i` and `j` and so, `R` has all values. But this calculation takes a lot of time. My machine's power was interrupted several times due to which I had to start over. Can somebody please help, how can I save R somewhere after every iteration, so as to be safe? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `saveRDS()` function to save the result of each calculation in a file.

To understand the difference between `save` and `saveRDS`, here is a link I found useful. http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2012/04/01/saving-and-loading-r-objects/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the R-workspace have a look at `?save` or `?save.image` (use the first to save a subset of your objects, the second one to save your workspace *in toto*).

Your edited code should look like

```
for(i in 1:100)
{
   for(j in 1:100)
    R[i,j]=gcm(i,j)
    save.image(file="path/to/your/file.RData")
}
```

---

About your code taking a lot of time I would advise trying the `?apply` function, which

> Returns a vector or array or list of values obtained by applying a function to margins of an array or matrix

You want `gmc` to be run for-each cell, which means you want to apply it for each combination of row and column coordinates

```
R = 100; # number of rows
C = 100; # number of columns
M = expand.grid(1:R, 1:C); # Cartesian product of the coordinates
# each row of M contains the indexes of one of R's cells 
# head(M); # just to see it

# To use apply we need gmc to take into account one variable only (that' not entirely true, if you want to know how it really works have a look how at ?apply)
# thus I create a function which takes into account one row of M and tells gmc the first cell is the row index, the second cell is the column index
gmcWrapper = function(x) { return(gmc(x[1], x[2])); }

# run apply which will return a vector containing *all* the evaluated expressions
R = apply(M, 1, gmcWrapper); 

# re-shape R into a matrix
R = matrix(R, nrow=R, ncol=C);
```

---

If the `apply`-approach is again slow try considering the `snowfall` package which will allow you to follow the `apply`-approach using parallel computing. An introduction to `snowfall` usage can be found [in this pdf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snowfall/vignettes/snowfall.pdf), look at page `5` and `6` in particular